# Are casts possible in scala

Tags: scala, casting, operators

I have the following method:

```
 def generateTokenForAccount(account: Account): Account = {
    account.setAccountToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    return account
  }
```

I am passing to this method a subclass of Account i.e. ChildminderAccount and I am trying to cast the result in scala to no avail. What I am getting wrong?

```
@Transactional
  def registerChildminderAccount(childminderAccount: ChildminderAccount): Boolean = {
    childminderAccountDAO.save((ChildminderAccount) generateTokenForAccount(childminderAccount))//problem here!!
    if (mailerService.requestChildminderConfirmation(childminderAccount)) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
```

I get the following error: `value generateTokenForAccount is not a member of object com.bignibou.domain.ChildminderAccount` as if I was invoking the generateTokenForAccount on the ChildminderAccount class.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *can* use a cast here, but in general in Scala `asInstanceOf` is a code smell (as is `return`). Try the following instead:

```
def generateTokenForAccount[A <: Account](account: A): A = {
  account.setAccountToken(UUID.randomUUID.toString)
  account
}
```

Now if you put in a `ChildminderAccount` you'll get out a `ChildminderAccount`.

Answer (score 4):

```
generateTokenForAccount(childminderAccount).asInstanceOf[ChildminderAccount]
```

Answer (score 4):

May want to use 'match' for better error handling

```
generateTokenForAccount(childminderAccount) match {
  case acc: ChildminderAccount => childminderAccountDAO.save( acc )
  case _ => // ERROR
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does the `generateTokenForAccount` return its input? This is deceptive, because it leads you to believe that it constructs a new, modified object, when in fact it does not; instead it mutates the object passed in. It should return `Unit` to indicate this:

```
def generateTokenForAccount(account: Account) {
  account.setAccountToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
}
```

Now the type guides you to see that you can simply use the effect in sequence:

```
def registerChildminderAccount(childminderAccount: ChildminderAccount): Boolean = {
    generateTokenForAccount(childminderAccount)
    childminderAccountDAO.save(childminderAccount)
    mailerService.requestChildminderConfirmation(childminderAccount)
  }
```

Also, whenever you have `if foo { return true } else { return false }`, this is equivalent to `return foo`. In Scala, the last expression in a block is automatically returned, so you can even remove the `return` keyword.